# How to center align a div with it having a specific width?

Tags: html, css

```css
body {padding: 0; margin: 0;}

div#container-one {
 background: #eee;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-size: 20px;
 background-image: url('https://i.pinimg.com/originals/ef/2d/b0/ef2db0885d94fd149a4b7914923bb2a3.gif');
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-color: #000;
}

div#container-one div.child-one {
 min-height: 600px;
 height: 100%;
 background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(70 70 70 / 60%), rgb(0 0 0 / 60%));
}


div#container-one div.child-one div {
 padding: 15px 20px;
 color: white;
 font-size: 25px;
 font-weight: bold;
 height: 93.5%;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 align-items: center;
 place-content: center;
    
 width: 750px;
 max-width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<body>

<div id="container-one">
 <div class="child-one">
  <div>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
   <p style="text-align:right;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

</body>
```

I want to center align a **div** with the parent element having a gif background; So I have to maintain a specific height for the element.
I want to keep the div container with a specific width such that when the window is bigger the container has a specified width instead of it covering the whole window, and when it is less than the container the height of the container expands.

I tried keeping the width and max-width values. But the text just flows out of the grid.
How can I fix this?

Comment: try `max-width: 750px;width: 100%;` instead :)

Comment: But how can I center align them vertically and horizontally without letting it overflow out of the box?